# Adding items to an object with ObjectListView

Tags: python, wxpython

After reading some items here I have decided to rewrite a little project using ObjectListView.  My problem is that when I try to do self.ListObject.AddObject(object) to add an item to my list it fails, and I am not sure why.

Here is the code where I let the user select a destination dir.  At the end of the selection process it is supposed to update the ObjectListView of ActionsOlv with a timestamp and the action taken.  Print statements are for debug only.

```
def onBrowseDest(self, event):
    print "OnBrowseDest"    
    dest = selectFolder("Select the Destination Directory")

    print dest

    self.txDest.SetValue(dest)
    self.anEvent = [Action(datetime.datetime.now(),dest,"Set as Destination dir")]
    self.ActionsOlv.AddObject(self.anEvent)
```

What is occuring is that I see lines being created in the list, but there is not any content to the line.  If I replace the AddObject method with SetObjects

```
    self.ActionsOlv.SetObjects(self.anEvent)
```

it will update the display, but each newline overwites the list instead of adding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue out.  I needed to use AddObjects, no AddObject